# How to change closed captions position on AMP (azure media player)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-media-services, closed-captions, azure-media-player

I have AMP implemented within the project to stream videos
and I wanted to know if there is an easy/native way to customize the Closed Captions positioning, for example, If I wanted to put it at the top of the screen or at the middle

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can put position coordinates on the .vtt file

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:04.000 position:10%,line-left align:left size:35%
Where did he go?

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:06.500 position:90% align:right size:35%
I think he went down this lane.

00:00:04.000 --> 00:00:06.500 position:45%,line-right align:center size:35%
What are you waiting for?
```